# How to use message.react with embed - Discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to react to a user's message after sending a command. I tried changing the position of the code, but it's not working.

```
let channel = message.member.voice.channel;

if (!channel) {

 // This Code was working without using embeds.
 // message.reply(`>>> Please join a voice channel`) && message.react('')


  return message.reply({
    embeds: [
      new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FFA400')
        .setDescription(`>>> Please join a voice channel`)
        // .message.react('')
        .setFooter(
          `Hey ${message.author.username}`,
          message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
        ),
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: `.reply()` returns a promise with the sent message, you have to resolve the promise then react to *that* message.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting
below code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Message.react`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react) and [`Message.reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) are separate methods. Make sure to put it **before** your return statement!

```js
if (!channel) {
  message.react('')
  return message.reply({
    embeds: [
      new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FFA400')
        .setDescription(`>>> Please join a voice channel`)
        .setFooter(
          `Hey ${message.author.username}`,
          message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
        ),
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow it worked! 
Thank You.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/15781079/mrmythical

Comment: If this answered your question, you can click the checkmark to show to others that it has been answered correctly. You can also upvote it by clicking the up arrow

Comment: Done.
Thank You.